# Python: Difference Between arg=(myDict,) and arg=(myDict)

Tags: python, arguments, tuples

In my python code, I have a class. I would like to run a method of the class in a thread. The method takes a dictionary as its argument.

```
def func1(self, input_dictionary):
    ...
```

In order for this method to run in a thread, I found out that I need to pass my dictionary to the function as `(mydict,)`:

```
threading.Thread(target=self.func1, arg=(mydict,))
```

I would like to know the difference between `arg=(myDict,)` and `arg=(myDict)`. What does the `,` after `mydict` do to the tuple?

Running the following will result in python complaining about `self.func1` takes 2 positional arguments and I have input the wrong number of inputs.

```
threading.Thread(target=self.func1, arg=(mydict)) # or the next one
threading.Thread(target=self.func1, arg=mydict)
```

Could someone kindly shed some light on this?

Comment: Any version of `arg=` is wrong - the parameter name is `args`. This might seem like a small detail to quibble about, but you just got bit by such a small detail. Please be more careful about stuff like that when posting. Such typos can obscure the actual cause of a problem.

Comment: Absolutely right. Sorry about it. I got distracted about the issue I was having and forgot about other detail in my post.

Comment: Removing the [multithreading] tag because this question and its answers have nothing to do with threads. It's just a question about the Python _language_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the ',' at the end makes the parentheses define a tuple. And without the comma, it is just redundant parentheses.

As to the 9 arguments as opposed to 2, what python is doing there is as following: It expects a tuple of arguments to unpack, so it tries to unpack the object it gets passed.

It turns out that my_dict has 9 values, so they get unpacked as arguments - giving 9 arguments in the function.

Comment: The concept of unpacking is new to me. Learned something today. Thank you for clarifying this in your answer.

Comment: Have a look at the * operator in python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

or here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misconception that parentheses create tuples in Python.

Passing `arg=(myDict)` is equivalent to passing `arg=myDict`, similar to how `(1) + (1)` is equivalent to `1 + 1` in maths.

It's actually the commas that make the Python parser decide that you're actually building a tuple. That means that, to make a tuple with a single element, you need to add a somewhat awkward trailing comma. You can check this behavior yourself in the Python REPL:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> type((1))
<class 'int'>
>>> (1,)
(1,)
>>> type((1,))
<class 'tuple'>
```

So in your case, you need to pass `arg=(myDict,)` to make sure your argument is passed as a tuple.

Comment: Great illustration! Now I fully understand it. Thank you.